# How can we skip display:none items in owl carousel?

Tags: owl-carousel

Can anyone please tell how can we skip display:none items in owl carousel?

My html is like this :-

```
<div id="owl-demo">
      <div class="item" id="image1"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item" id="image2"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item" id="image3"><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item" id="image4" style="display:none;"><img src="images/4.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item" id="image5"><img src="images/5.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item" id="image6"><img src="images/6.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item" id="image7"><img src="images/7.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item" id="image8"><img src="images/8.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
    </div>
```

Here is my jquery :-

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

      jQuery("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

          autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
          navigation : true,
          items : 4,
          itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
          itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]
      });

      //jQuery("#owl-demo").data('owlCarousel').visibleItems;
    });
</script>
```

Now the issue is I do not want to display the "display:none" items. Now the display none items are not coming but at the end there comes a space, that should not come.

Any one can help please?

Thanks.

Comment: Any solution please to remove lis with specific class from owl carousel? but those lis should stay there in ul with specific class or display:none. It should not be removed. I know we can do it by removeItem(index) but it removes whole item from from ul.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution. Well but not the owl-carousel way. It's not possible to skip the display:none items in owl-carousel. Here is the custom solution.

I took the new div in which I got the collection of lis but I gave them hid class so all will be hidden(hid = css class with display:none)  Then look at the javascript I put in code.

Html is like this :-

```
<style type="text/css">
  .hid{display: none;}
</style>

<button onclick="reinitcarousel(1)">Tab 1</button><button onclick="reinitcarousel(2)">Tab 2</button>
    <div id="owl-demo">
      <div class="item im1" id="image1"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item im1" id="image2"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item im1" id="image3"><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item im1" id="image4"><img src="images/4.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item hid im2" id="image5"><img src="images/5.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item hid im2" id="image6"><img src="images/6.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item im1" id="image7"><img src="images/7.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item im1" id="image8"><img src="images/8.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="anotherdiv" style="display:none;">
      <div class="item hid im1" id="image1"><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item hid im1" id="image2"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item hid im1" id="image3"><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item hid im1" id="image4"><img src="images/4.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item hid im2" id="image5"><img src="images/5.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item hid im2" id="image6"><img src="images/6.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item hid im1" id="image7"><img src="images/7.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
      <div class="item hid im1" id="image8"><img src="images/8.jpg" alt="Owl Image"></div>
    </div>
```

Script is like this :-

```
<script>
jQuery('#owl-demo .hid').remove(); //At the time of page load, first remove all lis having hid class

//Then load the carousel
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
      autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
      navigation : true,
      items : 4,
      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3],
      loop:true,
      rewindNav: false
  });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function reinitcarousel(v) //When you click on any tab
  {
    jQuery('#owl-demo').html(jQuery('#anotherdiv').html()); //Remove all lis in owl-demo div & place lis of anotherdiv div where all lis having class hid
    jQuery('#owl-demo .im'+v).removeClass('hid'); //Then again remove class hid having class .im(v) where v is a number
    jQuery('#owl-demo .hid').remove(); //Then remove all lis having class hid so our carousel will have only visible lis only

    jQuery("#owl-demo").data('owlCarousel').destroy(); //We need to destroy carousel first & then reinitialize like below
    jQuery("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
        autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
        navigation : true,
        items : 4,
        itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
        itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3],
        loop:true
    });
  }
</script>
```

Done :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Basicly your way is not correct. This kind of carousels firstly parse html and generate its own data then it start to loop with them. If you define some css property, you just break the carousel. So you should OwlCarousel's method for adding and removing items.

```
    //Initialize Plugin
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
     
    //get carousel instance data and store it in variable owl
    var owl = $(".owl-carousel").data('owlCarousel');
     
    //Manipulation methods.
    owl.addItem(htmlString [,targetPosition]);
    owl.removeItem(targetPosition);
```

I hope it sounds good...

Comment: Hi Sercan, First of all thank you for giving solution :) now the thing is can you please tell me what is targetPosition? Is it index of li like 0 1 2 etc...
Actually I want carousel to only take visible items means where there is not display:none or a class 'hidden' in which I define display:none. so whichever lis have hidden class, those will not be considered in carousel so any solution for that?

Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, targetPosition is a property defined the postion which you want to insert new item. And I've no proper solution for your problem.

Comment: Yes ok Sercan, but can you please suggest if I want to skip those lis with hidden class in carousel? It would be really great :)
Thanks :)

Comment: If you don't need them, remove before creating carousel @KA9

Comment: can we do like remove item by class? because we need those lis but do not want to consider in looping :)

Comment: Yes, sure: $('.classNameHere').remove()

Comment: no no Sercan, I mean the function of owl carousel or any custom function in owl carousel to remove slide with class instead of removing slide with index. Instead of removing slides, I am in need of a function that skips those slides in carousel.

Comment: removeItem(slideIndex) removes slide with index. But why do you need these hidden slide? Do you need them for SEO?